# multiple setting qtreewidgetiitem checksatate not working

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidgetitem

i have a `qtreewidget` with checkable items, i want to change state to be checked or not base on some value, first time i create `toplevelitems` i set item to be unchecked and it works, but after that when i want to checked it inside code it get checked but checkbox is not ticked when its shown.
first time i setstate code is :

```
  for(int i = 0; i < PermisionDataBase.allEvents().size(); i++) {
        m_eventList->addTopLevelItem(new QTreeWidgetItem);
        m_eventList->topLevelItem(m_eventList->topLevelItemCount()-1)->setText(0, PermisionDataBase.allEvents().keys()[i]);
        m_eventList->topLevelItem(m_eventList->topLevelItemCount()-1)->setCheckState(0, Qt::Unchecked);
    }
```

but after when i checked it, it doesn't checked

```
for(int j = 0; j < m_eventList->topLevelItemCount(); j++) {
m_eventList->topLevelItem(j)->setCheckState(0, Qt::Checked);
```

and i checked this items in if clause and i get they are checked, but when they are shown no item is ticked, mt if clause code :

```
for(int j = 0; j < m_eventList->topLevelItemCount(); j++) {
        if(m_eventList->topLevelItem(j)->checkState(0) == Qt::Checked)
            qDebug() << m_eventList->topLevelItem(j)->text(0);
    }
```

do you know what's wrong with it? thank you in advance

Comment: What happens when you try to check/uncheck the boxes using your mouse?

Comment: ticked and when i check if its ticked i got its checked

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the flag `Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable` that you have set.
For a `QTreeWidgetItem` to be checkable you need only use `setCheckState(0, Qt::Unchecked)`.

If you comment the lines where you set the flags i guess your code will work.

Comment: thanks for your help, i comment that line but nothing changed, i need both users and inside code i check the checkboxes, how can i do that? thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure you recompiled your code ? I have tried your code on my PC and when i remove the flags i am able to check/uncheck the boxes both from the code and the user interactions

Comment: yes of course i recompiled it, i edit my post to see my new code, thank you very much